# $x^3=y^3=1, xyx=yxy$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

The statement of the following problem from Artin's book is:

*Use the Todd-Coxeter algorithm to identify the number of elements in the group $G$ with the following defining relations: $x^3=y^3=1, xyx=yxy$. If it is possible identify the group}.*

After doing the Todd Coxeter algorithm, I find that the group $G$ can be embedded in $S_8$ by sending $x\mapsto (1)(2 \ 4 \ 5)(3 6 7)(8) y\mapsto (1 \ 2 \ 3)(4)(5 \ 8 \ 6)(7) $, and that the group has $24$ elements. My question was, can we identify $G$ with some very well known group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group is isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbb F_3)$, under the isomorphism
$$x \mapsto \pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1},\quad y\mapsto\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\-1 &1}$$
since $SL_2(\mathbb F_3)$ has order 24 and the given matrices satisfy the relations $x^3=y^3=1, xyx=yxy$ and generate $SL_2(\mathbb F_3)$.